# HTML List with changing options based on variable?

Tags: php, html, list, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

so this is my first thingy here so apologies if I don't get my question across quite correctly.

So I have a webpage, built on bootstrap, but I want one of the options in my navigation bar to change, based on whether or not the user is logged in.

This is what I've managed to come up with, but it just causes a constant loop of neverending redirects:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="inactive"><a href="****">****</a></li>
<li class="inactive"><a href="****">****</a></li>
<li class="inactive"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<li class="active"><?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['user']))
{echo '<a href="private.php">Account</a>)';}
else{echo '<a href="login.php">Log In</a>)';}
?></li>
</ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

I'm wondering if it's because I call Common again later maybe? Although tbh I probably just have no idea what I am doing :|

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Nothing in the code you've posted will cause a redirect.

Comment: in PHP header ("Location: private.php");

Comment: Agreed, that's what I thought when it happened.
Only happens when I add this code though.

Later on the page I run
`code`<?php
require("common.php");
if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
{header("Location: login.php");
die("Redirecting to login.php");}
?>`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, thank you for your help :)

Turned out I'd put a (!empty) instead of an (empty) so it would cause a constant loop back and forth between the two pages I was testing this idea with.

Thanks for your help and my apologies.

Comment: Please close your question then

Comment: Apologies, but how do I do that? Do I click delete or the big tick or something?